# bootstrap 3 moving 3 column to various break points

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am trying Bootrsrap push and pull but not getting exact output as shown on the image wireframe.
See reference : http://postimg.org/image/vse5tmjm1/

1200px above - 3 columns
990-1199 - move left column to downside
767 and below - right column also move to down right

Using bootsrap 3 can You suggest good grid code for me?

Please check the image wireframe diagram for various resolutions.

Thanks